# This SQL query never stops execution when data IN clause have a long list of data

Tags: sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    KV_CODE 
FROM 
    PERSON, PERSON2, ORGANIZATIONRIGHTS  
WHERE
    KV_CODE IN (1000 entries),
    AND ((EXISTS (SELECT kc_startdate 
                  FROM organization  
                  WHERE v_mainorgcode = kv_orgcode 
                    AND c_mainorgregistrynr = kc_registrynr  
                    AND (c_enddate IS NULL OR c_enddate = '' OR c_enddate >= '20161022')
                 )
        ))
     OR (v_mainorgcode IS NULL OR v_mainorgcode = '') 
     AND ORGANIZATIONRIGHTS.kv_personcode = '100000' 
     AND c_mainorgregistrynr = ORGANIZATIONRIGHTS.kc_orgregistry  
     AND v_mainorgcode = ORGANIZATIONRIGHTS.kv_orgcode  
     ABD (c_enddate = '' OR c_enddate IS NULL OR c_enddate >= '20161022')
```

Comment: Please add a tag to your question with the specific flavor of DBMS you are using (SQL Server? Oracle? MySql? PostgreSQL? ...).

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax with an appropriate `ON` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, never say never :-) although I also strongly recommend to use ANSI JOIN, there are databases, that in some context, does not  support ANSI JOIN, but only old style JOIN.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz . . . The only case of a recent version of a database that does not support a `join` is MS Access that does not support `cross join`.  I don't think its use should be encouraged, so I stand by my statement.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I do try to be precise as possible and I did say "in some context". Teradata does not allow the use of ANSI JOIN in the same scope you have used table functions with variables `[3706] Syntax error: Joined table is not supported in conjuction with table operators or table function invoked with variable input argument.`.

Comment: Using Join instead comma solves the problem, but I am still not clear why it happened.? Could anyone give me reason for that.

Comment: The above query works fine if IN clause have less data, but if IN clause  contains many values (over 1000) separated by comma than this problem of never ending execution  is occuring.

Comment: Please explain why it works if I change the comma separated join with proper join using join conditions.